Ghost Clicks in Ubuntu 24.04
There are ghost actions and clicks that happen as I login. The same happened to me in 22.04 too. For now my fix is to restart the pc until the problem disappears. But once in a while after booting up and logging in, it occurs again.
Any insights on what the problem might be about? or all the distros have the same issue?
Edit: This was because of the touchscreen becoming faulty.

In the login screen's password input field clicking on the tiny eye icon reveals what you've typed so far. If that doesn't correspond to what keys you pressed you can backspace back to the beginning and type your password again.

Yup! found it. It is because of my laptop touch that became faulty and I totally forgot about the touch as I was on mouse and keyboard in a static position set on a table ever since I started with Linux. I remembered that I disabled the touch in windows too using devices and drivers. Anyhow, I found my solution for disabling touch on Ubuntu using Wayland here and Ubuntu using Xorg here, also refer here and a little detail descriptive here [I followed this]
